# Meaning of "object of wrong GDALDatasetShadow" TypeError in GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, vrt

I have written a Python script which using gdal.Warp in order to get image from source and save it as TIFF image. Unfortunately I cannot share the full script, but I can tell that the error part comes from the gdal.Warp function:

```
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'projWin': bb, 'projWinSRS': igh, 'xRes': res, 'yRes': res}
#bb is bounding box 

ds1 = gdal.Translate(vrt_loc, link_layer, **kwargs)

ds2 = gdal.Warp('test/vrt2', 'test/vrt1.vrt', dstSRS='EPSG:4326')

#this is the part in the script that creates the error

#this is part of the callback
...

    675 if isinstance(destNameOrDestDS, str):
--> 676     return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)
    677 else:
    678     return wrapper_GDALWarpDestDS(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)

File C:\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py:4331, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
   4329 def wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args):
   4330     r"""wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(char const * dest, int object_list_count, GDALWarpAppOptions warpAppOptions, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None) -> Dataset"""
-> 4331     return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)

TypeError: object of wrong GDALDatasetShadow
```

What does this type error means? what is it missing? What can fix it?

Edit:

Added more information on the first code (the vrt1).
Also, when I try to visualize the layer of the link I get the following message:

```
with rasterio.open('/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay/clay_0-5cm_mean.vrt') as src:
    show(src.read(window=Window.from_slices((10000,15000),(10000,15000))), transform=src.transform)

>>>
RasterioIOError: Read or write failed. '/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay\./clay_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-006-008/tileSG-006-008_1-3.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

When I clink on the link of the tif, it download to my computer little island that suppose to have nothing to do with my bounding box.

this code is my attempt to do the same as mentioned [here](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/webdav_from_Python.md).

Comment: Try either including the file extension `'test/vrt2.vrt'` or specify the output format `format='VRT'`.

Comment: @user2856 gives the same error

Comment: its not really clear from your question how the `gdal.Translate` in/out relates to the `gdal.Warp` in/out. What is `vrt_loc` and `link_layer`?